# connection provider to read xls files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, connection-string

I used the below connection string to read xlsx files. Its working fine.

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\"";
```

Below connection string to read xls file is not working

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Excel 8.0;Extended Properties=HDR=NO;IMEX=1;Data Source=" + fileName + ";";
```

Please correct this. Thanks in advance

Comment: First one you have `Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\"` and second `Extended Properties=HDR=NO;IMEX=1;`. Try quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;
  Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

**"HDR=Yes;"** indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. 
**"HDR=No;"** indicates the opposite.

**"IMEX=1;"** tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers, dates, strings etc) data columns as text. Note that this option might affect excel sheet write access negative.

SQL syntax "SELECT [Column Name One], [Column Name Two] FROM [Sheet One$]". I.e. excel worksheet name followed by a "$" and wrapped in "[" "]" brackets.

Comment: I tried this, still getting error, "Couldnot decrypt file".     "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\""